# Unable to load prestashop after adding 'cybersource/rest-client-php' to vendor folder using composer

Tags: composer-php, autoload, prestashop-1.7

Added cybersource/rest-client-php to my prestashop vendor folder using composer. after that I am trying to load the prestashop in the browser. But it is throwing following error.

[image]

Comment: What have you tried to debug that problem? Is that class really missing?

Comment: Yes, I debug the problem. Found that that class was missing. So added the class in the path. But after that it was showing missing another class then I added that also but it was going so on. So it might be a problem in the library itself. So I left that and used another approach. Thanks, But sorry for the delayed response.